# how to attach a document via email automatically, when the document is edited or changed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

how to attach a document via email automatically, when the document is edited or changed. I wanted to send the particular document (irrespective of any version for ex: “1.0” or ”0.1”) directly through e-mail.
Note: Instead of opening the document and sending (without opening the document).

Comment: If I'm not too wrong, one great advantage of this comunity is knowledge sharing via questions and responses, beside people being really very responsive. By monitoring your threads for responses is the least proof of respect for all respondents doing it for free on their own time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see is to use a Workflow via the "Wait for a change" action (here you have to figure out your business needs) and use another custom activity freely available here http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/.

Other solutions would involve creating your own event handler to do a similar thing.